# Is there a way to write tests for 500 error page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom error pages in my rails app testing the 404 error seems straight forward enough (get nonexistent page and do assert_match/select for certain text) but I'm wondering how to test the 500 error page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So what I found out was that I could do something like this in rspec

```
def other_error
   raise "ouch!"
end

it "renders 500 on Runtime error" do
  get :other_error
  response.should render_template("errors/500")
  response.status.should == 500
end
```

Comment: To clarify, you're imagining an `other_error` method on some controller, not as a helper method in your rspec test, right? I'd love the latter to work, but think it's a dream.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I do, assuming you're using [rspec](/questions/tagged/rspec), [rspec-mocks](/questions/tagged/rspec-mocks) and [capybara](/questions/tagged/capybara):
First, you need to find a controller action that calls a method. For example, you might have a `UserController` with a `show` action that calls `User.find`. In that case, you can do something like this:

```
it "should render the 500 error page when an error happens" do
  # simulate an error in the user page
  User.should_receive(:find).and_raise("some fancy error")
  visit '/user/1'

  # verify status code
  page.status_code.should eql(500)

  # verify layout
  page.title.should eql('Your site title')
  page.should have_css('navigation')
  page.should have_css('.errors')
end
```

Comment: This returns a status code of 404 error for me, not a 500 :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rspec, you can use the `controller` block and define some test actions under test there:

```rb
describe ApplicationController, type: :controller do
  controller do
    def index
      fail 'Something bad happened'
    end
  end

  it 'returns an error page'
    get :index
    expect(response.status).to eq 500
    expect(response).to render_template 'errors/500'
  end
end
```

The `type: :controller` is important, otherwise RSpec doesn't expose the `controller` method (although you're probably doing that already).

Answer (score 0):

```
allow(User).to receive(:find).and_raise('500 error')
get "/users/#{user.id}"
expect(response.status).to eq 500
```