# Can't test content of custom 500 error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I've taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219058/is-there-a-way-to-write-tests-for-500-error-page-in-rails) and am still having no luck testing my custom error page. In development, everything works fine, I'd just like to know why my tests are doing what they are. I have my routes file set as follows:

```
# rest of routes file
match '/500', to: 'errors#server_error'
match '/:anything', :to => "errors#not_found", :constraints => { :anything => /(?!500).+/ }
#end of routes file
```

My ErrorsController:

```
def not_found
  render '404', status: :not_found
end

def server_error
  render '500', status: :internal_server_error
end
```

My 500.html.haml view:

```
.well.offset3.span6
  %h2 Something went wrong...
  %p We've been notified of this issue, and will get to work right away!
  =link_to "Home", root_path, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

My test:

```
scenario "An exception is raised in the application", js: true, focus: true do
  CallQueue.should_receive(:find_by_queue_code).and_raise("problem")
  visit "/"
  page.should have_content "Something went wrong..."
  page.should have_content "We've been notified of this issue"
  page.should have_link "Home"
end
```

Each time, the test fails because the page that is rendered is the WEBrick Internal Server Error page. Can anyone explain to me why this would happen in the test environment but not the Development environment (which I've modified to act like Production, setting `consider_all_requests_local` to false)? Or maybe I'm just going about it the wrong way?

Comment: how did you tell rails to render that error page?

Comment: @phoet I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I set `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` in my `application.rb` so I can handle exceptions on my own, and I'm matching the 500 error to render that view in my routes file.